# Database on Mobile Device ( BeagleBone )

Tags: csv, mobile, nosql, beagleboneblack

For a project, I have to record for long periods of time data on sensors linked to a BeagleBone. The BeagloBone is fixed to the installation and will never move.

At first I wanted to simply save temporarily the data on the beagle as CSV and upload it later to a MongoDB server on AWS, and query it there. But the Beagle will be connected to the internet later on in the project, and the customer wants to access his data now with an API already provided for other operations.

Is it a good idea to stock "large" databases on such a mobile device ? I'm talking about between 500 000 and 2 000 000 rows of data, in one or two tables. Would it be a better idea to stock it as CSV, or in a NoSQL database on the Beagle in order to already be able to easily query it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find the beaglebone to be under powered for large datasets. Single core, low ram and slow flash. It could work if you have no realtime or latency sensitive tasks running but I'd be weary of hogging what little resources are available to your other applications.